# FlowGear Email Watcher Node

Tags: flowgear

I'm trying to set up an Email Watcher node to watch a gmail account for incoming emails, and have specified the properties.  However, that step of the workflow fails with:

imap.gmail.com is not ready for : AUTHORIZATION.

Any idea what the cause of this would be?

Comment: Email Watcher is only for POP, use IMAP Watcher for IMAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [IMAP Watcher](http://developers.flowgear.net/kb/Node:IMAP_Watcher) instead of the Email Watcher node.

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea how I can specify a partial match for the 'Subject' property of the IMAP Watcher?  eg, where Subject LIKE 'some text ', or where Subject Starts with 'Some text'?

Comment: mmm...nevermind...I see now that Subject property is an OUTPUT of the node, and not an INPUT to the node.